How to escape an already escaped string in Regex
I am using the below code, as part of a script to turn a canonical name into a distinguished name.
However should I present the CN "test.example.com/This\/is\/a\/escaped/\space/\OU/person, I get way more than 1 OU in the resulting DN string.
How do I resolve this? I think the solution is to double escape the CN, no?
$DNOUMatches = $DNOUs | select-string -pattern '([^\/]+)' -allmatches

for($i=0;$i -lt $DNOUMatches.matches.count; $i++)
{
  $OU = $OU + "OU=$($DNOUMatches.matches[$i].value),"
}


Where did the original name come from? The AD directory service always works with DNs so I'd much rather be looking for a way to get the original DN from that source rather than convert it to an AD 'friendly' name (or something that looks not entirely like an AD name) and then back...

What's in your starting $DNOUs variable? A simple solution is to add in -notmatch "CN=" perhaps but seems a little unclear based on not seeing your data set and what you expect. I would not even use select-string and just iterate an array assuming $DNOUs is an array with both -match and -notmatch to get final expected result with Where-Object. Without data starting points and expected output clarification, we are left to guess based on what I'm seeing.

@grawity_u1686 Canonical name is to come from AD's Object tab, and the use case is Powershell cmdlets like get-adobject which seems to only accept GUID, and DN. Note though if there is an easier way to do this, I am looking to challenge myself, not find a different way to achieve this that wastes the time taken to script it thus far.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle $DNOUs comes from a substring of the Canocial name (i.e. test.example.com/This\/is\/a\/escaped/\space/\OU/person split into test.example.com (and processed through a similar loop as above), person, and This\/is\/a\/escaped/\space/\OU. I am unclear how match or not-match will get me an OU= portion that retains it's \/, or as it currently is (putting each /\ section in it's own OU=), and not exclude that section which is valid LDAP.

Can you clarify whether \/ is how the RSAT "Object" tab escapes spaces or slashes? If it escapes spaces as \/, what does it do for slashes?

@grawity_u1686 It doesn't escape spaces, at least as shown in the GUI. It escapes \ with a double of itself, in the GUI. But if I encounter one that is escaped from another source that uses Canocial, and I want DN, want to have the script account for that.

If you're after OU only, then would (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *).DistinguishedName not work for the need. I'm not sure why CanonicalName is the starting point still if you are after only the OUs. There is a property for DistinguishedName you can get that without filtering.

This post might help you otherwise but it's really not necessary if you can change the data to what you need rather than trying to transform it and have control over the process to change at that level: https://millerb.co.uk/2019/07/16/Get-DistinguishedName-From-CanonicalName.html

A regex that would work to weed out LDAP / escaped input strings would be (.+?(?<!\\))\/ utilising just reminded about negative look ahead ("<!X)) to make sure, in this case, a \ is not proceeded by a /.
Then a substring to remove the trailing /.
